# Get Data from SOAP output with namespaces PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, namespaces

I'm trying  to Extract the "Auv7cbb9Opa8/lbjVYLqVV03ELE=" value from below SOAP output. But it returns an emplty array . Can you please help me with this.

```
$gotContent ='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ns2:signOnResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.vx.com/omi">
             <sessionHandle>
                <ns1:handle xmlns:ns1="http://www.vx.com/schemas/OMItypes.xsd">Auv7cbb9Opa8/lbjVYLqVV03ELE=</ns1:handle>
             </sessionHandle>
             <result>
                <ns1:resultId xmlns:ns1="http://www.vx.com/schemas/OMItypes.xsd">admin</ns1:resultId>
                <ns1:resultCode xmlns:ns1="http://www.vx.com/schemas/OMItypes.xsd">0</ns1:resultCode>
                <ns1:resultText xmlns:ns1="http://www.vx.com/schemas/OMItypes.xsd">Success</ns1:resultText>
             </result>
          </ns2:signOnResponse>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>';

    $xml     = simplexml_load_string($gotContent);


    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', 'http://www.vx.com/omi');

    $session2=$xml->xpath('//sessionHandle');

    print_r($session2) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the element, but `print_r()` is notable bad at getting anything useful out of `SimpleXMLElement`s.  But also this is the level above what you are after.  So add the `ns1` namespace (you don't use the `ns2` one anyway) and add that and the `handle` to the XPath expression to get the data

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://www.vx.com/schemas/OMItypes.xsd');

$session2=$xml->xpath('//sessionHandle/ns1:handle')[0];

print_r((string)$session2) ;
```